# how to extract those elements from the list which have square bracket in c#

Tags: c#, list

how to extract those elements  from the list which have square bracket in c#

eg.

```
list<string> lst=new List<string>(){ "ABC","[ABC]", "AB[c", "AB]C","ab 1" "12a", "ab1","[abc 1]", "12","15","[XYZ-12ac]","ab 1", "[233]" };
```

From the above i want to create lists, like..

```
AlphaNumeric_List= {"AB[c", "AB]C", "12a", "ab1", "ab 1"}
OuterBrackets_List={"[XYZ-12ac]", "[233]","[ABC]"}
```

Comment: Did you try anything at all?

Comment: Which list would `"[abc"` go in? what about `"[ac]c"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
var OuterBrackets_List= lst.Where(s => s.StartsWith("[") && s.EndsWith("]");
var AlphaNumeric_List = lst.Except(OuterBrackets_List);
```

Comment: @OP may be this suffice your requirement but this solution includes `numeric` and `only alphabetic` in the `AlphaNumeric_List`

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach(string s in lst)
{
   if(s.StartsWith("[") && s.EndsWith("]"))
   {
         //add to OuterBracket_List
         OuterBracket_List.Add(s);
   }
   else 
   {        
       int n;
       if (int.TryParse(s, out n) == false)
       {             
            //add AlphaNumeric_List
             AlphaNumeric_List.Add(s);
       }
       else
       {
            //add n to Numeric List
       }
   }
}
```

**UPDATE 1**:

Above code deals with alpha-numeric, numeric and strings enclosed in brackets [].

**UPDATE 2**:

Probably all solutions here are including numeric values i.e. `12`, `15` and `ABC` in `AlphaNumeric_List`:

However only letters category is also there but I have differentiated your list into 3 categories of strings:

1. string `enclosed in brackets` ex. "[ABC]"
2. string `containing Alpha-numeric` ex. "ab 1"
3. string `containing numeric characters` only ex. 12

Here is updated code:

```
foreach (string s in lst)
{
    if (s.StartsWith("[") && s.EndsWith("]"))
    {
        //add to OuterBracket_List
        OuterBracket_List.Add(s);
    }
    else
    {
        int n;
        if (int.TryParse(s, out n) == false && isAlphaNumeric(s))                   
        {     
            //add AlphaNumeric_List
            AlphaNumeric_List.Add(s);
        } 
        else
        {
            //add n to Numeric List if required
        }
    }
}

//method to check string is AlphaNumeric Note: Regex can be used
public bool isAlphaNumeric(string strToCheck)
{            
    for (int i = 0; i < strToCheck.Length; i++)
    {
        if (char.IsLetter(strToCheck[i]) == false)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here is input:

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>() { "ABC", "[ABC]", "AB[c", "AB]C", 
                                        "ab 1", "12a", "ab1", "[abc 1]", 
                                        "12", "15", "[XYZ-12ac]", "ab 1", 
                                        "[233]" };
```

Here is output:

```
OuterBracket_List = {"[ABC]", "[abc 1]", "[XYZ-12ac]", "[233]"}
AlphaNumeric_List = {"AB[c", "AB]C", "ab 1", "12a", "ab1", "ab 1"}
```

Comment: This might be the least sexy, but it's also the most performant of all answers posted by far. And there's also a case to be made for simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

Use StartsWith\EndsWith(thanks musefan):

```
AlphaNumeric_List = list.Where(s => !(s.StartsWith("[") && s.EndsWith("]"))).ToList();
OuterBrackets_List = list.Where(s => (s.StartsWith("[") && s.EndsWith("]"))).ToList();
```

Comment: I don't think this is right, but I won't downvote as the OP question isn't exactly 100% clear.. but you likely should use `EndsWith` for close bracket. Also, my assumption is it should have both open AND close brackets to qualify as "outer brackets". I could be wrong though

Comment: @musefan - He isn't clear enough - thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are willing to use LINQ then like so...

```
//get list of values that are NOT wrapped in square brackets
List<string> AlphaNumeric_List  - lst.Where(x => !x.StartsWith("[") || !x.EndsWith("]")).ToList();

//get list of values that ARE wrapped in square brackets
List<string> OuterBrackets_List = lst.Where(x => x.StartsWith("[") && x.EndsWith("]")).ToList();
```

Comment: You could be right, but he is not specifically saying that he only wants items removed with brackets at begin or end.

Comment: @MaxMommersteeg: Of course he *might* have other requirements, but these are the only rules I can deduct from the example output provided